# Problem with database in CodeIgniter

Tags: database, codeigniter

I downloaded the last version of CodeIgniter and I tried to run a simple app. The code works perfectly without database, but when I added this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

the page went to blank.

I looked at the logs files but I didn't find anything, I check differents tutorial, but my database.php file looks correctly configured. I removed it from the array.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('');
```

and added to the controller this:

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

Then, this error appeared

```
An Error was encountered

Unable to load the requested class: database
```

What I do? Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the database you need to use the 'library' autoload instead of the 'config' auto load

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

This will actually automatically load up your configurations.

**UPDATE**

Another thing you mention in your question is that you 'add' that line,  you do not need to add that line, you are suppose to add the element to the array that already exists on that line.  You potentially could be overwriting other autoloaded libraries, I will need to see your `autoload.php` file to confirm this.

Comment: I wrote config, but it was libraries. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: I assume the missing single quote is also a typo?

Comment: let me see your autoload.php config file

Answer (score 5):

To autoload the database, you use `$autoload['libraries']`.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database')
```

Or, to load it manually, you use:

```
$this->load->database();
```

The [database driver](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) is not a normal library, it follows some weird [rules](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html).

Comment: don't you mean `$autoload['libraries']` ?

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Guess I need more caffeine.